# How can I prevent my <dl> from wrapping at very low resolutions?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div with a class col-sm-12 and inside of it, I have something along these lines:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Price:</dt> <dd>${{ number_format($listing->CurrentPrice,0) }}</dd>
    <dt>Status:</dt> <dd>{{ $listing->Status }}</dd>
    <dt>MLS Number:</dt> <dd>{{ $listing->MLSNumber }}</dd>
</dl>
```

I like the way it looks on a large screen but on a small screen, e.g. iPhone at 640px wide, the `<dd>` tags break onto another line even though there is plenty of room.

On a large screen, that section looks like this:

[image: Large Screen Screenshot]

When I go to the iPhone screen at 640px wide, it looks like this:

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

**How do I keep the `<dt>` and `<dd>` on the same line in Bootstrap 3 when I get to very small resolutions?**

Comment: Do you really need `dl` and `dt`, `dd` combination?

Comment: The absolute simplest way would be to set a min-width on your dl.

Comment: If not, please post a bigger code chunk, maybe a fiddle, with bootstrap CSS included, and it will be a lot easier to fix it, as I can see how it acts with bootstrap.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, what would be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented, simplest is a `min-width` on your `dl`, but you need to know the max width that a `dt` and `dd` can be together, lets say 250px, and setting your `dl` rule with `min-width: 250px;` will make it not break line.

A better way would be to use floats.

If you don't want line breaks, just add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.dl-horizontal dd` rule.

```css
.dl-horizontal dt, .dl-horizontal dd  {  
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
.dl-horizontal dd {
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Price:</dt> <dd>sjdsdjfhksjhfksjdh fkjsdh fkjsdh fkjsdh fkjsdhfkjs kfjhsdkf sdf jksdf ksdjhfks fdfsdf</dd>
    <dt>Status:</dt> <dd>{{ $listing->Status }}</dd>
    <dt>MLS Number:</dt> <dd>{{ $listing->MLSNumber }}</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand but what min-width am I adding to the dl @LGson?

Comment: Using min-width might not be the best but simplest way. If you know the max width that a dt and dd can be together, lets say 250px, setting your dl rule with `min-width: 250px;` will make it not break line. My other sample is the one to use, which works no matter how long content you have.

Comment: @LGSon why `width: calc(100% - 110px);` ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik The `width: 100px; margin-right: 10px;` becomes `110px` together, and needs to be subtracted from total width to make both `dt` and `dd` stay on 1 line. If not, they will overlap and as floats will the last element that doesn't fit, jump down to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the behaviour in your browser carefully while resizing the window, you'll notice that the following styles are applied to screens wider then 768px.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dl-horizontal dd {
        margin-left: 180px;
    }

    .dl-horizontal dt {
        float: left;
        width: 160px;
        overflow: hidden;
        clear: left;
        text-align: right;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

So to get that behaviour on small screens, all you need to do is add those style rules to your custom stylesheet, but outside a media query, so they get applied no matter the screen size.

http://www.bootply.com/htGYTQPo1N

Answer (score -1):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` for your element.

Comment: When you answer something, kindly check before you answer.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using `di` wrappers and CSS tables.

[`di`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-list.html#edef_list_di) was an new element proposed for XHTML 2, which could have been used to group `dt` and `dd` elements.

It doesn't exist in HTML5, but who cares?

```css
dl {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1em .2em;
}
di {
  display: table-row;
}
dt, dd {
  display: table-cell;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <di>
    <dt>Price:</dt>
    <dd>${{ number_format($listing->CurrentPrice,0) }}</dd>
  </di>
  <di>
    <dt>Status:</dt>
    <dd>{{ $listing->Status }}</dd>
  </di>
  <di>
    <dt>MLS Number:</dt>
    <dd>{{ $listing->MLSNumber }}</dd>
  </di>
</dl>
```